# Best (or any) Grails File Browser

Tags: file, grails, content-management-system

Another day another question ;)
This time I would like to ask you about server file browser in grails. To be more specyfic I'm looking for something similar to [this](http://ckfinder.com/)  in grails. I've looked at many sites and I only find Open File Manager attached to CKEditror plugin. In some way it's fine but with it I can't, for example, pick file (like in "Enhancing HTML form" in [CKFinder demo](http://ckfinder.com/demo))  
I would be very grateful for any suggestions

Comment: I finaly manage to find solution. What is intresting is a fact that already mentioned Open File Manager attached to CKEditror plugin has a possibility to do that. I only have to open it with new windows (target="_blank")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly manage to find solution. What is intresting is a fact that already mentioned Open File Manager attached to CKEditror plugin has a possibility to do that. I only have to open it with new windows (target="_blank")

Answer (score 0):

[Weceem](http://www.weceem.org/weceem/) is a CMS built in grails.  It has the ability to upload HTML files and do basic file management.

Comment: Thanks for such fast answer! However, as far as I know Weceem is a complete cms system, and I would like to have only elements connected with file management.