# grails: file manager plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, file-manager

I need to know if there is some free plugin that allows to have a file browser into a Grails application. An example of what I need is [here](http://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo). 
I've seen a similar question in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405965/best-or-any-grails-file-browser), but the solution is not good for me. Notice that the answer is given by who post the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try grails [elfinder-resources](http://grails.org/plugin/elfinder-resources) plugin([Demo](http://elfinder.org/)).

OR

[Download elfinder](http://elfinder.org/) and [install](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Install) in into your application directly.

Comment: Thanks! Which one is better for an existing Grails project?

Comment: My personal opinion is second, I have tested it, it works fine.

Comment: I've seen that it's php. Don't you think that is weird to mix codes?

Comment: `Grails elfinder-connector plugin` helps you to remove that php code. Have a look at http://grails.org/plugin/elfinder-connector. I used this in place of the php code.

Comment: <script>
 $().ready(function() {
  var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
   url : '${g.createLink(controller:'elfinderConnector')}'
  }).elfinder('instance');
 });
</script>

Comment: If I understand well, you have downloaded elfinder source code and installed the connector plugin. Where do you have put the source code downloaded?

Comment: Exactly. Follow the installation steps mentioned at https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Install. Install the plugin, add folder location in  config `grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir = "PATH_TO_ROOT_DIR"` and replace script(php) code to pligin script code(in the page where you want to show the files)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42610/discussion-between-francescods-and-user1690588)

Comment: if the elfinder-resources is not installed it seems to not work...ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found